# How to migrate an Android Studio project to Android.mk based project to be built as part of AOSP build?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-source

I have project in Android Studio 4.2
But want to have it under AOSP source tree and want it to be build as part of AOSP build.
If there is a way of easily convert Gradle based project to Android.mk project I would be very happy.

Comment: Nothing automatic. Manual work to port the dependencies and the makefile

Comment: Also, use Android.bp. The new (and easier) way.